# Esconder barra de endereços em dispositivos móveis

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

Existe alguma forma de esconder a barra de endereços em navegadores de dispositivos móveis?

Comment: A gente não tem controle sobre o navegador, é só sobre a página. Se tu tá precisando esconder algo do usuário, é melhor fazer uma página que faça uso do POST.

Comment: Eu já testei alguns scripts até meta tags, porém não funcionou.

Comment: Ofereça um aplicativo que mostre uma WebView em tela cheia do seu site a quem possa interessar e deixe o site para quem quer um site com tudo que tem direito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infelizmente de forma "nativa" não. Esse é um comportamento que apenas o próprio browser utilizado pelo usuário pode fazer. O chrome por exemplo esconde quando o usuário faz scroll na página. (acredito que outros também façam o mesmo).

Para "contornar" essa necessidade existem outros recursos que você pode recorrer:

1. Exibir a página em fullscreen utilizando a [API Fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API), o problema dessa solução é que para inicializar a funcionalidade é necessária a ação do usuário (como apertar em algum botão ou tecla específica).
2. "Imitar" a ação de scroll. Essa solução irá esconder a barra de navegação em navegadores que tem esse comportamento ao rolar a página para baixo. Porém quando o usuário fazer o scroll para cima novamente a barra irá aparecer. Basta adicionar esse código após o carregamento de sua página: `window.scrollTo(0,1);`. Obs: você também dependerá de sua página ter "espaço" para o scroll.